# SQLPackage Error when trying to release my pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-agent, sqlpackage

I have installed an Agent pool in my Azure VM. I am trying to deploy a dacpac file using the agen pool but I get the error No agent found in pool which satisfies the specified demands: sqlpackage, Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.103.0

I have installed the sqlpackage.exe within the VM and even added the path to the environment variable but I still am getting this error.

Comment: Are you able to provide your YAML? Does your pool have multiple agents and if so do all agents have SQLPackage installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check that you use a corresponding agent pool.
2. Check these capabilities on your build agent ([View agent details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities)):

2.1. Agent.Version. [How do I make sure I have the latest v2 agent version?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#how-do-i-make-sure-i-have-the-latest-v2-agent-version)

[image]

2.2. SqlPackage. SqlPackage PATH (with your local path) should be added after installation, you can try to restart your build agent to re-read your environment.

[image]

Comment: I have checked the capabilities and the SQLPackage path is correct but still I am getting the error

Comment: @weewoo do you use in your build the agent pull that contains your build agent?

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked it just took a while for the changes to affect the pipeline

Comment: Just to be more specific: You need to find the location of `sqlpacakge.exe` and add it to the `path``system environment variable, then restart your host. Then you'll see `sqlpackage` appear in the agent capabilities in Azure DevOps. I'm not sure why standard sqlpackage install doesn't do this automatically.